# SQL Server linked Server (on Oracle DB) displays tables in duplicate

Tags: sql-server, oracle, linked-server

I have set up a linked server on a on a SQL Server 2016 (SP2-CU4) (Windows Server 2012R2 ) for an Oracle DB (version 12.1.0.2.0) for data migration purposes. Now I see all the tables in duplicate and can not explain where this comes from. See the screenshot:

[Screenshots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hUEGn.jpg)

What also seen on the screenshots is that when I call the ORA Info View ALL_TABLES, the tables are NOT duplicated. Also when I click on a table via SSMS via "Script Table as" | "Select To" generate a Select script, all columns are duplicated also.

The whole thing is not a problem for me now, I would still understand where it comes from!

regards Volker